# PayPalの定期支払いの失敗理由について

Tags: paypal

自分が把握している限りの定期支払いが失敗する理由は以下ですが、
ほかに考えられる理由はありますか？

1.利用限度額等による残高不足の場合
2.クレジットカードの有効期限切れの場合
3.クレジットカードの利用停止が行われた場合
4.何らかの理由によりクレジットカードの失効が行われた場合

また実際にどのような理由により継続課金に失敗したかを調べることって出来るのですかね？

Answer (score 1):

私も具体的には思いつかないところもありますが、
例えば何らかの理由でクレジットカード利用に問題がある場合か、
何らかの理由でPayPalアカウント側に問題や制限がかかっている場合などもありますよね。

直接PayPalに問い合わせるのがいいかと思います。
（ただ、PayPal側もカード会社から詳しくは聞けないとは思いますが...）

また、PayPalのデベロッパーサイトには、各APIごとに発生するエラーコードとその内容が記されているので、ここが参考になるのではないでしょうか？
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/

なお、sandboxでは、決済金額に上記エラーコードを小数点で指定することで対応するエラーを発生させることもできます。ここで実際にテストしてみるのもよいでしょう。
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_error-conditions/